# Reading a text file and store it in a 2D array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, text-files

I have a text file written in the following manner

```
0 1
1 1
0 1
0 0
```

I wrote the following C code in order to read the file and store it in a 2D array

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i, j;
    size_t size = 5; /* 5 characters in a single line */
    char *string;
    FILE *file = NULL;
    int states[4][2];

    string =  malloc(size);

    file = fopen("position.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
       printf("Error while opening the file ");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    i = 0; 
    while (getline(&string, &size, file ) != -1) {  
        for ( j = 0 ; j < 2; j++)
            sscanf(string, "%d", &states[i][j]);
        i++;
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for ( j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++)
            printf("%d", states[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(file);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But when I display the content of the array I get the following:

```
00
11
00
00
```

So can anyone help out and tell me how to get the right values stored in the array?

Comment: Remove the loop `for ( j = 0 ; j < 2; j++)` and do `sscanf(string, "%d %d", &states[i][0], &states[i][1]);`. Currently in this loop you scanning the first int on that line, therefore your output is basically the first column twice.

Comment: I encourage you to check **sscanf* return the right number to check the validity of the inputs